# What are the reasons behind the Chinese consulate asking for more documentation for a tourist visa?

Tags: visas, china, tourist-visas

My partner and I are applying for tourist visas to visit China. He is US-born, US ancestry, etc. and his application was approved within a day.

Meanwhile, I’m having the toughest time with my application. We’re working with an agency, and they’ve come back to me every other day stating the Chinese consulate needs more documentation from me. I was born in the US. My father was also born in the US to Chinese parents, and my mother is a naturalized US citizen (born in China). Since my partner’s application was approved so quickly, I doubt it has anything to do with our trip in question. Is it more about my nationality? What is tripping them up?

Comment: As a wild guess, because of your Chinese ancestry, they may be trying to figure out if you are actually a Chinese citizen under Chinese law.  The fact that the US considers you to be a US citizen doesn't necessarily preclude this.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_nationality_law suggests that a relevant question would be whether your mother had "settled" in the US at the time of your birth.  Does the requested documentation seem related to that?

Comment: That’s interesting. I’ll have to ask my US-born Chinese friends if they’ve gone through this hassle when applying for visas. And yes, the requested documentation seems to be about my parents’ citizenship now. Sigh, all this to visit some extended family and see some sights!

Comment: They might think you are a spy given your ancestry. It might sound far fetched but it's not. My wife is a immigration consultant and she sees this kind of reasoning all the time